# My toilet on 2nd floor fills up with black swelling water

Tags: toilet

I live in a house that is 120yrs old, 3 floors and 3 toilets. We have city sewage, no pump. 2nd floor toilet fills up with black gross smelly water, when you drain bathtub on 3rd floor or run kitchen sink on 2nd floor. What is going on? Ive snaked this toilet many times, still unable to clear clog. I only see leaves and toilet paper in this foul black water. Can anyone point me to a different route? I also climbed on smaller roof and didn't see anything down vent stack. Flushed it with water hose and it filled that same toilet up again with that black smelling water.

Comment: It sounds like you need a professional plumber or drain cleaner to handle this.  The clog is probably partial and past the toilet.

Comment: Leaves? Is there a tree above the roof whose leaves can fall down a plumbing vent? I've heard of squirrels causing problems by putting nuts down such vents, but leaves are odd. Maybe leaves have been accumulating faster than they can rot for 70 years? I don't understand why they wouldn't just drain through to the sewer, though.

Comment: Is there a sink or toilet on the first floor and does that work ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.